# Cannot get files added by other developers in ankhsvn

Tags: svn, visual-studio-2012, visualsvn-server, ankhsvn

I and a colleague are working together on an ASP.NET project. We are using Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate and **AnkhSVN 2.5** for version control.

I initially set up a subversion repository in my colleagues PC using **VisualSVN Server 2.7.7**. Then my colleague added her Visual Studio project to the repository, and I checked out the Subversion project from within Visual Studio in my PC.

**Both of used the same Subversion user**

However, if I add any new folder containing some new files, and then commit, my colleague does not receive it even after updating the project to the latest version. The problem occurs vice versa too.

**Our PCs are connection across a LAN.**

But if use a repository browser and go to the repository I can see the files listed there.

I tried simulating the situation in my own PC (1 repository, two working directories in **same PC**)
I could not reproduce the problem.

Comment: Have you tried to update your working copy with TortoiseSVN? What is happening?

Comment: when using only using tortoise svn the problem goes away ... but every time i do it i have to close visual studio ... which is troublesome .... isnt it doable from ankhsvn?

Comment: First - it's strange that you have to close VS (for me update works using both AnkhSvn and TortoiseSVN with opened VS). Second - does ankh svn show right repo URL on top of its Pending changes window?

Comment: Do you observe the same behavior when using VisualSVN client? http://www.visualsvn.com/visualsvn/ If not, then it could be some bug in AnkhSVN. However, I guess that's some kind of pilot's error.

Comment: @bahrep I think I have got the problem. When we commit we explicitly leave out the .csproj file, which contains the names of all files included in the project. But we do not want to commit the csproj file since each of us are working on different modules. What to do?

Comment: @Shuaib I don't know your repository structure and workflow, but I can suggest to use branches for your projects and merge your changes in a master branch when needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the 100% correct answer why this happens, you should run `svn info` in your and your colleague's working copy and show the result of the command.

These are several recommendations for your case:

1. Make sure that both of you have the same URL of the versioned project. If both of you work on the project's `/trunk`, then make sure that your working copies correspond to the `/trunk`'s URL.
2. Working under the same user account is awkward. You use VisualSVN Server, so there are no issues with creating 2 user accounts: for you and your colleague. If you use Subversion authentication and authorization in VisualSVN Server, then you can create these accounts in a couple of clicks via VisualSVN Server Manager console.
3. Learn how to use [branching and merging](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.branchmerge.html) in Subversion. It will help you to understand how development with Subversion works, will allow you to determine the best repository structure for your team's project and will definitely help you to rule-out silly errors in future.
4. Read [SVNBook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/)!